# Calling Object from 3D Matrix with a for loop

Tags: arrays, object, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have an array of maps with x and y coordinates, and an each (x,y) coordinate relates to a number. I collected a bunch of these maps with the same dimensions and organized them into a 3D matrix.

Now I want to call all of the numbers in the x,y coordinates for all times one at a time.

I thought it would be like

```
    for t in Map_Collection:
        for x, y in Map_Collection[:,:,t]
            print Map_Collection[x,y] 
            #hoping it would give a large list of single numbers
```

This didn't work out giving me multiple errors and I can't figure out the cause. But I think my entire logic might have been off.

To clarify I wanted to be able to find each number each coordinate of the map for each time-stamp, and use it in a separate function which I already have.

Please help.

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting.

Comment: Could you please edit your question more carefully.  Statements like "find each number each coordinate", or "and an each (x,y) coordinate" make others have to guess at what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start simple:

```
 map=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
 for t in map:
     print t
     print
```

produces

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

[[12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23]]
```

That is, each `t` is a `row` (1st dimension) of `map`.

You tried to use `t` as the last index.  To do that you need to generate a range of numbers, e.g. `[0,1,2...]`

```
for i in range(map.shape[-1]):
    for j in range(map.shape[1]):
        for k in range(map.shape[0]):
            print map[k,j,i]
```

Will print all the entries in `map`.  It's not pretty, but it gives you a starting point.  You may need to reorder the iterators.

Here's a way of using the 'rows' to work your way down to simple entries:

```
for t in map:
    for x in t:
        for y in x:
            print y
```

gives the values in the order that `arange` generated them (and the order in which they are stored in `map`.